# Cleaning contacts

Tags: contacts, database

How do I identify the contacts who haven't opened any mailings in the last 3 years?

I'm unsure which are the appropriate fields in the Advanced Search to make this process as easy as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE civicrm. There isn't an easy way to do it, but you do it with some extra clicks.

Step 1:

You can use Mailing Open report(/civicrm/report/Mailing/opened?reset=1), find the mailing opened in the last 3 years, and Add all those contacts into a group using the action drop-down appearing on left side of the report.

Step 2:
Using Adv Contact Search(/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1), find for contacts with Activity type => Bulk Email, Activity date => last three years =>> Search =>> Add contact to Smart group

Using Include / Exclude Search(Search >> Custom Search) => Find for contacts from group created at step2 and excluding from group created at step 3.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 2):

We have used the Synopsis extension to generate a tab like this

[image]

An example of the json involved is

{
"Label": "Total Emails opened in last 90 days",
"MName": "Total_Emails_opened_in_last_90_days",
"DataType": "Integer",
"SelectRef": "none",
"existing_field": "0",
"Query": "SELECT  count(*) as opened\n            FROM\n              civicrm_mailing_event_queue q\n              INNER JOIN civicrm_mailing_event_opened o ON o.event_queue_id = q.id\n            WHERE\n              q.contact_id =  {contact_id}\n\t\t\tand CAST(o.time_stamp AS DATE)  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW()\n\n",
"Optgroup": "undefined",
"Remove": false,
"Hidefield": false,
"CFID": 200,
"Weight": "9",
"column_name": "total_emails_opened_in_last_90_d_200",
"table_name": "civicrm_value_synopsis_28"
}

Comment: And being synopsis you should then be able to search those fields, filter, add in reports etc. probably even make smart groups

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using GDPR extension https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr

Navigate to Contacts >> GDPR Dashboard or navigate to civicrm/gdpr/settings

Comment: good to know - hmm actually i do not see 'when was mail opened' in my settings. perhaps i am on old version?